# ¿problema frentea tipo de salida de informacion?

Tags: python, visual-studio, input, tuplas, str

la question es la siguiente, estoy haciendo practicando (nivel amateur/novato) un programa que simule una cuenta bancaria en la cual se ingrese el nombre y apellido seguido mostraria el menu conformado por mostrar ahorros, agregar saldo y retirar saldo, el problema que tengo es al mostrar el menu me sale el siguiente error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Cuenta bancaria.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(prueba)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

```
        import os, sys, random
    os.system("cls")
    
    class Persona():
        def __init__(self) -> None:
            Intentos_fallidos = 1
            self.nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ").capitalize()
            self.apellido = input("Ingrese su apellido: ").capitalize()
    
            while self.nombre.isnumeric() or self.apellido.isnumeric():
                os.system("cls")
                self.nombre = input("Error al digitar\nVuelve ingresar tu nombre: ").capitalize()
                self.apellido = input("Vuelve ingresar tu apellido: ").capitalize()
    
                if Intentos_fallidos == 1:
                    sys.exit("Numero de intentos fallidos, vuelva intentar más tarde") #Revisar mas adelante
                Intentos_fallidos += 1
    
    class Cliente(Persona):
    
        def valor(self):
            valor_cuenta = random.randint(50, 1000)
            return valor_cuenta
        
        def menu(self):
            opciones_menu = {1:"Mostrar Saldo", 2:"Consignar", 3:"Retirar"}
            return opciones_menu
    
        def __str__ (self) -> str:
            os.system("cls")
            menus = self.menu()
            mensaje = f"Bienvenido señor {self.nombre} {self.apellido} su saldo actual es ${self.valor()}" 
            print(mensaje)
            op =[""]
            for n in menus.keys():
                op = f"{n} {menus.get(n)}"
                print(op)
            return
    
    
    prueba = Cliente()
    print(prueba) #linea 42
```

he intentado usar la función `str` en la linea donde se presenta el error y en la variable menus pero no ha funcionado, ¿como puedo arrglar este problema?

Comment: El `return` de `__str__` no está regresando nada y debe regresar un `string` no sé que quieres que diga al final pero por ejemplo si pones `return 'Fin'` va a funcionar y después de imprimir el menú va a imprimir Fin.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, funciono!!!!!!!!!!!!!!